# A linear map $T: \mathbb{C}^7 \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^7$ such that $T^2 + T + I$ is nilpotent?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials

I am trying to find a linear map $T: \mathbb{C}^7 \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}^7$ such that $T^2 + T  + I$ is nilpotent.

My idea was to find a $7 \times 7$ matrix $A$ with entries in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $(A^2 + A + I)^2 = 0$. I know that, since $f(x) =(x^2 + x + 1)^2$ is an annihilating polynomial for $A$, the minimal polynomial for $A$ divides $f(x)$, and the roots of $f(x)$ are $\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{3}i}{2}$, the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ must belong to the set $\{\frac{-1 + \sqrt{3}i}{2}, \frac{-1 - \sqrt{3}i}{2}\}$. The diagonal matrix $A$ with diagonal entries in this set will certainly do for a matrix $A$ such that $A^2 + A + I = 0$ -- but how do I modify this matrix to get one such that $(A^2 + A + I)^2 = 0$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any matrix satisfying $A^2+A+I=0$ will also satisfy $(A^2+A+I)^2=0$.
I presume though you want a matrix $A$ with $A^2+A+I$ nilpotent but non-zero.

Let $\omega=\frac12(-1+i\sqrt3)$. Then the Jordan form of an $A$ with $A^2+A+I
=(A-\omega I)(A-\omega^2I)$ nilpotent will have Jordan blocks, of any size, with
entries $\omega$ or $\omega^2$ on the diagonal. So I suggest maybe
$$A=\pmatrix{\omega&1&&&&&\\&\omega&1&&&&\\&&\omega&1&&&\\&&&\omega\\&&&&
\omega^2&1&\\&&&&&\omega^2&1\\&&&&&&\omega^2}$$
for your matrix (omitted entries zero). It satisfies $(A^2+A+I)^4=0$
but $(A^2+A+I)^3\ne0$.

Comment: Incidentally, since $7$ is odd, this argument also shows that there is no real matrix satisfying the criterion.